# how to append link to text block using Safari Extensions

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I'm trying to create a safari extension that will place an "Add to BibDesk" link after any text that looks like a [BibText](http://www.bibtex.org/) entry. BibText entries look like [this](http://www.bibtex.org/Format/):

```
@string{
    foo  = "bar",
    foo2 = "bar2"
}
```

I know how to construct the necessary regex, but my question is **what's the best way, using javascript, to search all the text on a page for a particular bit of text?**

Answer (score 0):

Get any elements that can contain text nodes (div, p, etc.) using a selector, then for each element search for any BibText entries and replace the matched text with itself PLUS the link that does the work appended to the end.

Comment: "Any elements that can contain text nodes?" That could literally be anything, couldn't it?

Comment: @eykanal: Basically. Not all elements though. `img` elements don't have text nodes.